# bash script list files from given user

Tags: bash, shell, ls

I have a problem with this one.
It is constantly returning me, not a directory, but is certainly is

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash  
DIR=$1  
if [ -d "$DIR" ]; then  
        ls -1Apl /home/$DIR | grep -v /\$  
else  
        echo "not a directory"
fi
```

One more thing, I need a little hint.  I have to list files from a given user in a given directory, where I get both the user and directory as parameters.
Just suggestions, please.

Comment: If one of our answers helped you solve your problem, you should click the check mark by it to indicate that. (If not, you're welcome to edit your question so we can give a better answer!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you in the `/home` directory when you run this? If not, you may want to change it to:

```
if [ -d "/home/$DIR" ]; then
```

to match the `ls` command. This is assuming you're running it with something like `myscript pax` to examine the `/home/pax` directory, which seems to be the case.

And if you want to only list those files in there owned by a specific user, you can use `awk` to only print those with column 3 set to the desired value (`$usrnm`), something like:

```
ls -1Apl /home/$DIR | grep -v /\$ | awk -v user=${usrnm} '$3==user{print}{}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not testing for the existence of the same directory as you're trying to list - maybe you mean `-d "/home/$DIR"`? Or from your requirement, do you have two parameters?

```
user="$1"
dir="$2"

# and then examine "/home/$user/$dir"
```

Comment: thanks guys... this is almost done, i have one more question, but i have to write another topic, this Answer your question thing is not working. thanks again